# How to express the meaning that I am trying to figure out a concept?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/427680/244425) just now

> What an input space exactly is in the context of machine learning?

I am not sure where should I put "exactly", which one in the following is more appropriate?

- What an input space exactly is?
- What is an input space exactly?
- What exactly an input space is?

If there is any other expression that is more clear, please tell me.

Comment: *"What is an input space exactly?"* This is better than the other two. The other two I would say is very uncommon. Even better is this: *"What  exactly is an input space?"*

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that your examples are awkward, but not because of the usage of "exact". Lets first look at them without that word:

> - What an input space is?
> - What is an input space?

Of these, only the second ("What is an input space?") is natural. The first has an odd placement of the verb form "is", and is not likely to lead to a natural usage with 'exactly" added.

So now let's consider how to add "exactly".

> - What is an input space, exactly?
> - Exactly what is an input space?
> - What, exactly, is an input space?

Any of these would be acceptable in my opinion, but the third I think is much the best. It emphasizes "exactly", and makes it clear that it modifies "what". I can't specify a clear rule or guideline with this result, however.